# Problem with Publishing app on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, apk, publish, google-play-console

When I login in my console account, my app's Status show draft but when I click on it shows ready to publish.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

- When you have not completed the entire publishing process for your app and have left it over incomplete at that time, your app is shown under the Draft section.
- Now, for hte status 'Ready to publish'...States that the APK that was built was successful and it has no issues with the Package names, Contents, Size of the app, etc. and is ready to be Published after Reviewing the app once.

Go inside of your Release Management section of your app and complete all the **pending** steps! Click on the Publish button or else check if something is missing then in the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your app, then just go at the Release Management tab inside the menu.
then click on `Publish for Production` in your app. Because currently, your app is in the draft.